# How do I make windows vm to send network traffic to remnux vm in vmware player

Tags: networking, virtual-machine

I am doing malware analysis of a pdf file in windows vm. This malicious pdf file is going to connect to the internet and I don't want it to. But I want to see the network activity it is going to do.
I watched in a video that I can connect the windows vm to some other vm like remnux and  test the packets being sent through wireshark.
If somebody wants to watch the video I am talking about here is the link: -https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNlRDNt7Zp0 
She talks about the remnux thing in between 15:00 to 16:00 min. I don't understand how she did that. 
Can somebody please explain me how those steps are done. I have searching the net all day but I can't find anything. I am really a beginner in all that networking stuff so any topics I did find were just jargon to me.
Thank you for your help. 
I am using VMware player version 7.

Edit: I did do a lot of research on this topic but whatever is available on google is far too much for me to understand. Please don't think that I didn't try anything myself.

Answer (score 0):

Malware is likely to generate a DNS request to resolve the ip of the C&C server. Therefore you can set the DNS in the victim (windows) machine to the ip address of the remnux machine and you will get the DNS request generated by the malware. You can then configure remnux to direct the malware to the same remnux machine to monitor traffic generated by malware when it tries to connect to C&C server after DNS resolution.
You may have to write a custom server for responding to the malware request. Modern malware use RSA challenge which will almost render initiating communication impossible.
Ref SANS tutorial for further details

Comment: raghu - thats still too tough for me but anyways thanks for answering.